# python [if key in dict] is not working without a break statement

Tags: python-3.x

So, I have a dictionary {d} which has about 200,000 data. **d.key** is a string, **d.value** is a tuple which has 2 strings.

```
d = {id1:(parentId1,name1), id2:(None,name2), id3:(parentId3,name3), ... }
```

If parent does not exist, parentId=None. And I have a List which contains about 1000 data. The structure look like:

```
alist =[ [id1,parentId1,name1],[id2,parentId2,name2],[id3,parentId3,name3], ...]
```

I want to mutate the name in alist so that it contains hierarchy path based on parentId. When I execute following code:

```
for a in alist:
    parentId = a[1]
    while parentId:
        if parentId in d:
            a[2] = d[parentId][1] + '/' + a[2] 
            parentId = d[parentId][0]
```

It runs forever. I checked with print statement, the code below [if parentId in d] never run. However, if i put a break statement like this:

```
i=0
for a in alist:
    parentId = a[1]
    while parentId:
        if parentId in d:
            a[2] = d[parentId][1] + '/' + a[2] 
            parentId = d[parentId][0]
        i=i+1
        if i > 200000:
            break
```

It works. Why?

Comment: You could have an actual infinite loop. Two IDs pointing back at each other

Comment: `while parentId` is an infinite loop if `parentId` was not in `d` you have to add an `else: break`

Comment: shooooot. That is right. This is a so low mistake. Shame on me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I'd be you my friend. I would remove the line `while parentId:`.
And use `if parentId in d:` only.

Good luck!